# Radius of Convergence (Complex Series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm suppose to find the Radius of Convergence of following complex series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+a^n)z^n$$

I tried to solve it by Ratio test but then got stock in the middle.

Thanks.

My attempt:

Ratio Test: 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+1+a^{n+1})z^{n+1}}{(n+a^n)z^n} = |z| \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+1+a^{n+1}}{n+1+a^n}$$

How am i suppose to solve now?

Comment: It would help if you show where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: What is $a$? Is it real?

Comment: @Trevor Norton... Well, in my question its not specified but I'm pretty sure it's just a real number

Comment: You can try breaking up your fraction and finding the limits of each piece. Your answer will depend on the value of $a$, so you will have to specify the ranges of $a$ for which the radius is valid.

Comment: In using the ratio test, you take absolute values.

Comment: if $|a| > 1$, divide every term in top and bottom by $a^n$. Then each term will converge. If $|a| \le 1$, divide every term in top and bottom by $n$. And again every term will converge.